# Looking for a Ruby/PHP file explorer

Tags: web-apps, file-management, php, node.js, ruby

I'm looking for some fancier replacement of apaches directory listing.

It should be a webbased fileexplorer which just displays the files inside a specific subfolder.

It would be great if it also had support for showing images, texts and maybe playing back videos.

Handling uploads is a plus but not a strict requirement.

Owncloud is too bloated: I don't want to use third party apps besides the webapp itself.

Security is not an issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I just found http://larsjung.de/h5ai/ which is quite beautiful.

It creates thumbnails, features up- and downloading several files at once and even comes with markdown-support and syntax-highlighting for textfiles.

Check out the demo at: http://larsjung.de/h5ai/sample

If you know other solutions, feel free to answer them as well!